# Connecting edges with eachother to extend a bevel

Tags: edges, bevel

so i am modeling a 3D "dollar bil" and i am having an issue, i want to bevel the sides of the bil so it becomes round, but the bevel only moves until an edge(see 2nd picture) so i think i need to combine or connect the 2 edges (the orange and white edge need to becone one) but i don't know how, i hope you can help.  [image]

[image]

Comment: As well as @Gordon Brinkmann's answer, it looks from your second image as if you may need to apply the scale to your object so that the bevel is symmetrical round the corner.. - In Object mode, CTRL-A > apply Scale.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, I guess you're right. If the scale was correct the beveling would look different. I just focused on the problem of joining the edges, but for a good bevel the scale should be applied, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go into *Vertex Select* mode, select the vertex which splits the edge and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to dissolve the vertex.

Or press <kbd>X</kbd> and in the popup menu choose *Dissolve Vertices*.

Just a sidenote, apart from the split edge it looks like the object bevels unevenly on both sides, so as @JohnEason mentions in his comment it is probably needed that you apply the scale on your object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*.

Comment: This worked Thanks!

Comment: @RyanvanVuure You're welcome. You might consider to accept this answer then.